# List or array in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, list

I'm looking for a way to use an instance of ruby as an array or list that can be used in "for/in" statement in javascript.
In controller I have:

```
@enum_Expected = Source.all
```

How can I use @enum_Expected in my view as a array or list that can be used in javascirpt like:

```
for (var source in WantToList){
  do something with each @enum_Expected's element
}
```

Thanks

After done in "mchail" issue.
Let's look at my result:
I used:

```
@enum_Expected = Source.all.to_json(only: [:latitude, :latitude])
```

When I debug, it has value:
"[{\"latitude\":10.7779,\"longitude\":106.656},{\"latitude\":10.785,\"longitude\":106.663},{\"latitude\":10.7709,\"longitude\":106.673}]"

When I try something like:

```
  for(var locat in enum_expected){document.write("Trying ")}
```

The result is:
  Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying Trying
  Thu number of "trying " words is equal to **locat.length** that say 137.
  It's not the result I expected. It's better if the number of "trying " words is only three, the numbers of records in **Source**.
**Any comment??**

Comment: You should really standardize on lowercase, underscore-separated variable names like `@enum_expected` if you're going to write software in Ruby. This is an *extremely* strong convention in the Ruby community.

Comment: `for...in` is a bad way to iterate over arrays in javascript. The iteration order is not guaranteed and you can see some extra elements, too

Comment: `Source.all.to_json` will give you a JSON string, so your JavaScript variable `enum_expected` is a string.  When you iterate over a string as you're doing in `for(var locat in enum_expected)` you'll iterate once for every character, which is why you have so many "Trying"s.  You need to turn that JSON string into a JavaScript object.  Try modifying @mchail's answer by doing `var enumExpected = JSON.parse(<%= @enum_Expected %>);`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, convert `Source.all` to json like this:

```
@enum_Expected = Source.all.to_json
```

If you only want to pass certain attributes through, you can do this:

```
@enum_Expected = Source.all.to_json(only: [:attr1, :attr2])
```

Then you can print your json straight to the view (erb formatting shown):

```
var enumExpected = <%= @enum_Expected %>;
```

Then use `enumExpected` in your `for` loop just as you would expect.

#### UPDATE

The json generated looks great. It generates an array, so you'll need to iterate over the array a bit differently. Like so:

```
for (var lolcatIndex = 0; lolcatIndex < enum_expected.length; lolcatIndex++) {
    var lolcat = enum_expected[lolcatIndex];
    console.log(lolcat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign `@enum_Expected` as an array of hashes in a variable.

```
<script>
  var enumExpected = <%= @enum_Expected.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
</script>
```

`enumExpected` should be an array of attributes for each `@enum_Expected`